# How do you create a trigger in Oracle Data Modeler?

Tags: database-design, oracle11g

This might be a simple question, but I cannot find any Oracle resources in the User Guide for Oracle Data Modeler on how to create a trigger (other than its definition in the Data Flow section of the manual)

Imagine for a moment:
I have a table in the relational model and I've created a sequence for it through the physical model using Oracle Database 11g.

- `GROUP` (table with id and name columns)
- `GROUP_SEQ` (sequence that increments by 1 starts with 1)

Now I'm trying to create a trigger through the modeler to auto-increment the id. I can do this through manually writing the SQL after generating the DDL, but in actuality, I have around 22 tables. I'd very much like to do this through the Oracle Data Modeler.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the suggestions in [this post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1120520)?

> open physical model, find "tables" node (in physical model) in the browser and you'll find triggers branch under 
>   each table represented in the browser - you can create triggers there using pop-up menu.

Comment: And how can I manage this for all tables? I don't want to add the same trigger for each table step by step...

Answer (score 4):

In Relational Model open properties for a table, next Columns, open properties for column you want to autoincrement, select Auto Increment and check mark Generate Trigger. Sequence will be generated also if not specified on last screen.